# How would I get text from an input 'type=text' element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Provided I cannot edit the HTML code at all how would I do this?

```
<input type="text" id="Identifier"     
class="inputControlFlexWidth" value="" tabindex="9" size="25" 
name="texthole">
```

I'm guessing this has to be a timed event such as

```
setInterval(ObserveInputValue(), 100);
```

Because the input can happen at any time.

I then want to use this text to update a URL.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
<input id="ServiceRequestEditForm.CustomObject6 Name.hidden" type="hidden" value="" 
tabindex="-1" name="ServiceRequestEditForm.CustomObject6 Name.hidden">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is

```
$('#Identifier').blur(function(){
    $(this).val();
});
```

**Explanation:** When the input loses focus, grab the value of the field.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4DtUh/

---

**EDIT**

*As per the comments...*

@Interstellar_Coder is right about spaces inside the `id`.

So, instead of using the `id` as the "hook", you could use the `name` attribute:

```
$('input[name="ServiceRequestEditForm.CustomObject6 Name.hidden"]')
```

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/4DtUh/10/

Comment: This is very helpful. I'm still struggling though. I put the updated code in my post.
I need to get the value of the hidden id once it changes. At the moment your code doesn't do anything when I select the hidden ID?

Comment: You can't have spaces in your id.

Comment: I can't not have spaces in my id. This is not relevant to the question.

Comment: It's relevant if you know what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 5):

You can add an event listener for the `change` event, then do whatever you need to in there.

```
$('#Identifier').change(function(){
   //do whatever you need to 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing so complex. You can just use `.val()` to get the value. In your code you would do:

```
$('#Identifier').val()
```

Take a look at the documentation for [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)